# android gridlayout column width exceed parent (gridlayout) width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview, android-gridlayout

I am using `gridlayout` to group my views. inside it, I have two columns. one column has a child which is `relativelayout` and the other column has a child which is `linearlayout`.

My `linearlayout` orientation is `vertical`. it has two views, textview and an imageview.

The issue is when I type text in the `textview`, **and the text is long**, I cannot see

- some characters  in the `textview`
- `imageview` which is below the `textview`

`textview` width is extending and **and hiding some of it's characters and also imageview before entering 2nd line(textview is muitiline)**

**I don't want** to use margin to solve this issue because if I use it, and the text in `textview` is short, unwanted space will appear at the right side of textview.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_gravity="fill" >
        </RelativeLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_gravity="fill">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12345...50" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/vladmir putin"/>

     </LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

How can i solve the issue of textview width exceeding gridlayout width?
if i type `1234` everything is ok. but if i type from `1` to `50`, i can't see some numbers like from `30` to `32` and imageview?.

Comment: What exactly do you want for a result? Do you want your text to go to the other line or to just cut the text off an put ... sign at the end?

Comment: @Aksiom my textview is inside a vertical linearlayout. and in this layout, i want every view including textview to be aligned on the right. so when textview width increases, some views below it cannot be seen

Comment: @Aksiom  please see my edited question.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @vojta kindly see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and aligned my `textview` to the start of the `imageview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:columnCount="2"
app:rowCount="1"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profile"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="12345...50"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/profile">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```